Cant Retrieve Deployed Smart Contract After Restarting Spring Boot Project
i just made a spring boot application with web3j to interact with an blockchain network. I connect my app with Polygon Network. the deployment to the polygon network is successful and i can retrieve the data after the deployment
But. after i restart my spring boot app to adjust something in my controller. suddenly my code cant retrieve information that i insert into the smart contract even thought the smart contract already exist in the polygon network. can someone explain why this happen?
i use infura and metamask to deploy my solidity smart contract to the polygon amoy testnet network
I just noticed that this was something that happen in web3j. i didnt know that i cant retrieve my data after i restart my spring boot project. i just want to be able to retrieve a deployed contract from the polygon network even after my spring boot project restarted (because i cant keep my computer on just to keep the data)
